# Найти наибольший прямоугольник в матрице

Tags: python

Следующий код находит самый большой прямоугольник в матрице, состоящий из единиц. Как я могу изменить этот код, чтобы учитывались так же и прямоугольники под углом?

```
def largest_rectangle():
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    maxarea = 0

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            for height in range(1, rows - r + 1):
                for width in range(1, cols - c + 1):
                    valid = rectangle_area(grid, r, c, width, height)
                    if valid:
                        maxarea = max(maxarea, width * height)

    return maxarea

def rectangle_area(grid, r, c, width, height):
    for r in range(r, height + r):
        for c in range(c, width + c):
            if matrix[r][c] == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Примеры прямоугольника под углом:

**1 1** 0 0 0
0 **1 1** 0 0
0 0 **1 1** 0
0 0 0 **1 1**
1 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 **1 1**
0 0 **1 1** 0
0 **1 1** 0 0
**1 1** 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1

Прямоугольник с прямыми углами:

0 0 **1 1** 0
0 0 **1 1** 0
1 0 **1 1** 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0

Comment: Что такое "параллелограм в матрице" и под каким "углом"?

Comment: @Igor исправила вопрос, извините, не знаю как лучше обьяснить. С этим кодом я могу найти больший прямоугольник, который имеет прямые стороны, другие примеры показывают что прямоугольник может быть "под углом", максимум +- 1 элемент.

Comment: Ага, начинает проясняться.

Comment: искать две "1" и дальше смотреть диагонали, но прямоугольниками я б их не назвал)

Comment: @MikeWaters должно работать и с большим количеством единиц в ряду, пример с двумя чтобы объяснить. :)

Comment: @WSzum, ищешь 1, дальше смотришь во все стороны ища 1, например справа есть,  значит позиция такая-то, длина 2, направление вверх и вниз, а дальше уже идешь вверх - вниз узнавая длину прямоугольника, для под углом так же но направление другое, и искать не вверх - вниз а в зависимости от направления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valid = rectangle_area(grid, row, col, width, height, 0) or rectangle_area(grid, row, col, width, height, -1) or rectangle_area(grid, row, col, width, height, 1)  

def rectangle_area(grid, r, c, width, height, delta):
    for r in range(r, height + r):
        for c1 in range(c, width + c):
            if grid[r][c1] == 0:
                return False
        c = c + delta
    return True
```

Добавьте в `rectangle_area` проверки на выход за пределы матрицы.

Comment: if grid[r][c] == 0: IndexError: list index out of range. Если использовать try/except, то счет получается не верным.

Comment: @WSzum Я же написал, что нужны проверки на выход за пределы матрицы.

Comment: @WSzum Если использовать для этого `try`/`except`, то надо возвращать `False` из `except`.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: На некоторые примеры все равно выдает ответ больше на две единицы, чем нужно. Что может быть причиной? try/except?

Comment: @WSzum Я не вижу, какой код Вы запускаете.